# Bayesian spatial autoregressive (SAR) model with heteroskedasticity in R

Tags: bayesian, heteroscedasticity, spatial, autoregressive, inla

In socio-economic data, I always found heteroskedasticity that can't be solved using transformation.I had read a paper "Spatial autoregressive models with unknown heteroskedasticity:A comparison of Bayesian and robust GMM approach". In this paper, I know solution the problem of heteroskedasticity in SAR, but I have difficulty to apply Bayesian method for SAR model with heteroscedasticity in R. I have tried using R-Inla, but it turns out that it is for homoscedastic models.

My question is how to implement SAR model with heteroskedasticity using the bayesian approach in R?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: my question is, how to implement SAR model with heteroscedasticity using the Bayesian approach in r?

Comment: How to do something in R is off topic, but you could ask about the general logic of the model which would give you a good enough understanding and allow implementing the model it in any language.

Comment: I think all poisson models and perhaps binomial as well are heteroscedastic, right? Anyway, look into GEE models: I've seen an application of GEE models that were used to model poisson overdispersion, and the variance was a function of something